# VENV Not showing the correct Python version

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv, python-venv, pyvenv

I have default Python version 3.9.6 on my Mac
and I need to work on a project on Python version 2.7 so I install it successfully V 2.7.12

Now I am using this command to create a new env with Python v 2.7
`virtualenv -p python2.7 env27`

this is the output:

```
created virtual environment CPython2.7.12.final.0-64 in 156ms
  creator CPython2macOsArmFramework(dest=/Users/omar/Frappe/env27, clear=False, no_vcs_ignore=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=/Users/omar/Library/Application Support/virtualenv)
    added seed packages: pip==20.3.4, setuptools==44.1.1, wheel==0.37.1
  activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,NushellActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator
```

now when I access this env and activate it using `source bin/activate`
and run `python -V` command it gives me 3.9.6 not 2.7.12
while the bin file has files of 2.7, not 3.9 and

I tried the same thing with Python 3.10 and the same thing happened it still shows 3.9.6 !!

any help ??

I tried many time with other python versions but same issue appear

Comment: Please share more information. Which OS are you using? How did you install virtualenv?
looking at the trace it seems you are using Mac OS.

Comment: `type -a python` ?

Comment: @oz123 Yes, i am using Mac OS,
and install it using: virtualenv -p python2.7 env27

Comment: @phd 
python is /usr/local/bin/python

Comment: After `. env27/bin/activate` it must be `…/env27/bin/python`. If it's not — something is wrong. If you cannot find what is wrong use full path to the python like `…/env27/bin/python -m pip install …`

Answer (score -1):

This most likely, because you use virtualenv version which is recent, and it does not support python2.7.
Just guessing though.

Comment: I don't think that, because i just tried with version 3.10 and it still shows me version 3.9